# android - convert dp to float

Tags: android, font-size

My font size is 12dp.

I'm setting the font using `TextPaint`, since I'm using a span.  The problem is the parameter that `TextPaint` accepts is in float.  I'm wondering how can I convert 12 dp to float?

Answer (score 21):

From `android.content.res.Resources.getDimension(int id):`

```
float twelveDp = TypedValue.applyDimension( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12, 
                mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics() );
```

Comment: applyDimension (int unit, FLOAT value...) not DP. This solution convert float to float, not DP to float.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
public static float dipToPixels(Context context, float dipValue){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,  dipValue, metrics);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try following:

// Convert the sp to pixels

```
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
int mTextSizeP = (int)  getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.text_size) / scale );
```

I have already have text_size defined in `res/values/dimens.xml` :

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="text_size">12sp</dimen>
</resources>
```